# Why does Larry Carlton think Dmajor scale when some plays Gmajor7 chord?

Tags: theory

In this video at 5:25 Larry says when someone played a Gmajor7 chord he thinks to play a Dmajor scale as those are the money notes.

What is the theory behind that thinking?

Comment: The GMaj7 is the IV chord of DMaj7, but so what.  What this amounts to is using G Lydian over the Gmaj7 chord which adds a sharp 4th.  This creates more tension and produces a darker sound in the melodic theme.

Comment: I think he means the D major _chord_, not scale. At what exact minute:second time position does he say he means the _scale_? I watched through this video too because it was suggested by Youtube.

Comment: At 5:35 ... "these are the color notes ... the money notes".

Comment: @RandyZeitman at 5:28 he outlines a D major chord. He does not play randomly selected notes from the D major scale. From the D major scale, he could also have selected all of the notes that are in a Gmaj7 chord, - or he could have outlined an even more colorful A major chord, but the_point, _color notes to play on a written Gmaj7_ is to outline a D major chord. Thinking about an entire _scale_ is not helpful in pop songs, if you want to add "money notes" to a solo. What do you do with an entire scale - select notes from it randomly, and every note in the scale will be a color note?

Comment: He plays eight notes. Are they arpeggios of D or a scale? I don't see any mention of random.

Comment: @RandyZeitman He outlines a D major chord and then a couple more notes, because he can't resist making it sound like an actual line from somewhere. Think about it. "What are the color notes to play on a Gmaj7 in Larry Carlton's style?" - _"Any notes from the D major scale"?_ That would be completely absurd. He does not arpeggiate an Em chord, not an A major chord, not a Bm chord, not a G major chord, not a Gmaj7 chord, none of the other stuff that could be done with notes from the D major scale. He plays a D major chord. Those are the color notes, the money notes to play on a written Gmaj7. :)

Comment: A couple more notes ... of what?  I've no idea why 'Any notes from the D major scale' would be absurd - I'm a novice. Why not just state the notes he plays so we all have our answer?

Comment: @RandyZeitman Don't you know what's the difference between playing just any notes from a major scale vs. playing tonic/subdominant/dominant chords using notes from the scale? Can you accompany Happy Birthday with just any combination of notes in any order as long as they're from the major scale? Everything works the same, same feeling and color, no matter which combination of notes you select? Btw, Rick Beato's newest video says something about the Larry Carlton thing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pH0S4MRbw74&t=10m15s   If you need further "proof", he mentions "upper structure triads". :)

Comment: @piiperi  ???... yes, I think everyone would understand that playing different notes results in different music. My statement isn't in relation to a song, it's in relation to him strumming a single chord.  Could you please list the notes he's playing in his phrase against the chord?

Comment: @RandyZeitman I think you'll find out what the notes are just fine without external help. If you're happy with the explanation that anything pulled from the D major scale like it was G lydian works as color notes for emphasizing a Gmaj7 chord, and that's what Larry Carlton did in his recording sessions, then that's perfectly OK. I just wonder if you've actually tried out any of this stuff on songs that have maj7 chords. Excellent song choices to try it on are What's Going On by Marvin Gaye and Imagine by John Lennon. I hope you'll realize how unsuitable Lydian mode is for the songs. ;)

Comment: @piiperi  Why wouldn't anyone be happy with that explanation. Yet a third time ... I am a novice ... I can't possibly know if someone's explanation is right or wrong. Is there some reason you're not asking that person? "I just wonder if you've actually tried out any of this stuff on songs that have maj7 chords." No! (... as above ... novice...) I said nothing about lydian mode ... ggcg did.

Comment: @DavidBowling Lydian gives a nice jazzy sound in its own right and you can get Lydian by overlaying a D major scale on a G chord, nothing wrong with that. But Lydian is not what Larry Carlton's maj7 coloring trick is about at all, it's about the triad as you say. It seems that the problem with many guitarists is, they're not fluent with the components of traditional functional harmony and they want to see everything as a scale or a mode. So "D major" must mean the D major _scale_, unless explicitly stated otherwise. What can you do? It's not a bigger deal than that, just talking about music.

Comment: @RandyZeitman why you shouldn't be happy with the explanation: because you _try_ it on actual songs and you hear what Lydian does to the chords. And then you try the upper structure triads, playing a major triad rooted on the fifth of any maj7 chord, in actual songs. It's simple and works on any maj7 chord without even knowing what the scale is. Don't get stuck in scale/mode thinking. In the history of jazz, modal playing came _after_ the more traditional and basic chord playing, and beginners should learn basics first. :) Also, watch the next video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pH0S4MRbw74

Comment: I found this other example which may be speaking about the same, or similar topic. 
Triadic Soloing by Larry Carlton
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5s2V6KRQVFw

Comment: @piiperi I'm happy with the explanation because I understand it, not because I think it's the best explanation ... yet still again ... third time now ... I ... am ...a ... novice.

Comment: Do you understand this: when you see "Gmaj7", you play the notes D - F# - A. When you see "Cmaj7", you play the notes G - B - D. When you see "Fmaj7", you play C - E - G. For Dmaj7: A - C# - E. For Emaj7: B - D# - F#. For Abmaj7: Eb - G - Bb. For Ebmaj7: Bb - D - F. Etc. You take the _fifth_ of the chord and play the notes of a simple major triad chord rooted on that fifth. In Gmaj7 the fifth is D. So, D - F# - A.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Playing D major over Gmaj7 creates the sound of the Lydian mode. These days, most jazz players prefer to use Lydian instead over the major scale (Ionian) - it's part of the sound of jazz since about the 1970s.

The only difference between the major scale and the Lydian mode is that major has a natural 4, while Lydian has a #4. This #4 (also a #11) is considered to be more colorful than the natural. The natural 4 is often referred to as an "avoid note," but the #4 blends more easily with the major 7th chord quality.

I think there is even more insight buried in this quote. He doesn't say, "I play the Lydian mode," he says he plays D major, and that's what has the "money notes."

As players, it is natural for us to start our scales on the root note, but when we improvise, constantly starting on the root of the chord can sound cheesy. By thinking of the scale as D major, he is more likely to start on the D, which is the 5th of G. This has some melodic advantages because when you play the scale ascending in eighth notes, the 7, 9, and #11 notes will land on the downbeats. Conversely, starting a run on the root, will lead to the blander root, 3, 5, 7 notes being emphasized. So by thinking about the scale as having a different root from the accompaniment, he is setting himself up to play more interesting lines.

Comment: Odd notes on even beats is a simple, powerful, insightful statement!

Comment: "he is more likely to start on the D" -- somehow I doubt that Larry Carlton has any difficulties starting on whatever note he wants to....

Comment: @DavidBowling Fair enough, but in the context of the video, he is talking about things he played when he started out and didn't know any theory.

Comment: 'If he's thinking D major, he's more likely to start on D'...When you get to where Larry is, there's probably a bit more (or quite possibly a lot less!) thinking going on. He's most likely past that stage; he was at that point 50 yrs ago!

Comment: The D major scale happens to have all the notes of a Gmaj7 chord, so why doesn't he play _those_ money notes? Is there some fake money in the scale too? If only some notes of the scale are the real money notes, then wouldn't it be more helpful to think in terms of reduced note sets that contain only the actual money notes, and none of the wrong ones. We could call those reduced sets like ... _chords_ or something.

Comment: The question is based on a false premise, and the answer getting upvoted and accepted... it makes me sad. Are guitarists really that hopeless. Lydian mode? Searching for starting points for scale runs, because guitar solos are made of scale runs? "Odd notes on even beats"... what? That way you will never understand what Larry Carlton is doing. :) There's a whole world of things built from the notes of a major scale, and you can use the same notes to e.g. make it feel like the harmony is at rest/tonic, or leaning to subdominant or dominant side. Same scale, but completely different feelings. :)

Comment: "Odd notes on even beats"... what? ... refers to Peter's insight. The question is based on a false premise? ... all I did was ask what he meant.

Answer (score 2):

He means the chord. "D major over G." D major chord over G. **Chord symbol: D/G**. You can play that in place of Gmaj7, and it will do the "maj7" thing, but in a more colorful way. It's almost Gmaj9, but leaving out the usual G and B notes of a regular G major chord, assuming a bass player plays the G. You can play a maj9 chord almost always if there's a written "maj7", and if you want it to emphasize the chord's "maj7" color, you play only those notes. D/G is kind of like "more strongly maj7 than maj7 itself", playing V chord while keeping bass at tonic.

The thing that happens when you choose to make a regular major chord a maj7 by adding a major seventh note is, it says that it's *not* a *dominant* seventh chord. It's like reminding the listener where the harmony is leaning. If you play a V triad while keeping the bass at I, it emphasizes the major seventh note even more.

If you want to do a similar thing with a dominant seventh chord, you play a *minor* chord. For example if you see a G7 chord symbol, and want to do a similar thing as Larry Carlton's "color notes, money notes", you outline a *Dm* chord in your solo, so Dm/G. It highlights the dominant seventh note even more than a regular G7. (In addition to that there are other "color notes" chords for a G dominant like Ddim, Ddim7, or "Fm7-5")

By the way, a D/G is sometimes called a "Steely Dan chord", because many Steely Dan songs have that type of chord in many places. For example "Don't take me alive", on the lyrics line "With rage in your eyes and your megaphones", the chords are: Bb/Eb -  C/F - D/G. (And then it continues with even more of the same chord type)

Comment: Well he says "scale" so why do you say he means chord?

Comment: No mention of either scale or chord at that point. But playing the notes from D major *chord* will be 2/3 of Gmaj7 anyway - all he's adding is 9, making Gmaj9. A very common occurrence in jazz.

Comment: @Tim Exactly. But pay attention to which notes of Gmaj9 he's _not_ playing... particularly, he leaves out the B note, and that's how you get the Steely Dan chord. :)

Comment: You're forgetting that the accompaniment is still playing the chord Gmaj7, so the B is still present - Carlton is soloing on the chord extensions. The overall harmony still contains the major 3rd (B), so it's a Gmaj9 not D/G, which is a type of suspended chord.

Comment: @Peter I'm not forgetting anything. It's about emphasizing colors when soloing. Try it yourself, it's not hard, you just need to know which notes are relevant and characteristic for each moment of the harmony progression, keep track of where they are, and emphasize each case by playing color tones. For example, on a written dominant seventh chord: play a minor, diminished or dim7 chord rooted on the fifth of the original chord. Or in this particular case, on a written maj7 chord: play a major chord rooted on the fifth of the original chord. You don't even need scales or modes to do this. :)